# Do reads to physical endpoint return most recent version

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Our CosmoDB is distributed across two regions, A & B, with eventual consistency. ALL reads and writes are via a physical endpoint to region A.  In this configuration will reads always return the most recent committed version of a document?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you stay within a single region and remove region B completely, your data may still be spread around multiple replicas within that single region. The delay is extremely small, but has to be expected.

Source:
[What does "absence of any further writes" mean in documentDb eventual consistency model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43551520/what-does-absence-of-any-further-writes-mean-in-documentdb-eventual-consistenc)

> Within single region configurations, you have at most a few milliseconds lag between replicas in practice

Your queries might read from a replica that does not have the most recent version.

Comment: Too bad. We would like the equivalent of strong for a physical endpoint to one region with eventual or bounded staleness to a second. The point of the second region is to get a "current" replica for disaster recovery (and possibly read-only loads).

Comment: Its an interesting idea. I don't think its even possible right now to actively select a certain region for your reads/writes, it just selects the one closest to you. You might need to build something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/multi-region-writers to get where you want, but it will take some extra work on your end. Maybe you could pitch the idea to the CosmosDB team. Btw. If you feel your question was answered, it would be appropriate to mark the answer as accepted using the green checkmark. This helps others who use the platform.

Comment: Having spoken to MS apparently Bounded Staleness can work this way (which is why it requires twice the resources. there is even an option to set staleness to zero and get synch replication.